# Rails 5 and Rspec 3.5: application_controller method in a view partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Just started learning Rspec, and I'm trying to test for the existence of the header partial on my Home page, and then later on the rest of my pages.

My header partial uses a current_user method from application_controller.rb

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end
```

to test whether or not a User is logged in

```
  <% if current_user %>
    <%= image_tag(current_user.image_url, size: "30", :class => "profile_image") %>
  <% end %>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
    <% if current_user %>
      <li><%= link_to "TODOs", todos_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to "Log In", 'auth/google' %></li>
    <% end %>
```

Attempting to test my view:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "home_page/home.html.erb", type: :view do
  context "When viewing the home page" do

    it "the home page should render the _header partial" do
      render :partial => "layouts/header"

      expect(view).to render_template(:partial => 'header')
    end

  end
end
```

Returns

```
 Failure/Error: <% if current_user %>

 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<#<Class:0x007fc9d85409f8>:0x007fc9d77a4858>
   Did you mean?  current_page?
```

I want to test this both when there is a logged in user and when there isn't, but I'm unsure how to stub this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your `rails_helper` you should have...

```
require 'devise'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # For Devise <= 4.1.0
  # config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
  # Use the following instead if you are on Devise >= 4.1.1
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

then in your tests you can do...

```
before(:each) do
  user = User.create(name: 'John') # <-include other params as req'd
  user.confirm! # if you're using devise's confirmable module
  sign_in user
end
```